# Editable div for comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make comments on my website. I want to edit this comments dynamically. I mean, that now I have my comment in div. After click on "Edit" span, I want to change this div to editable textarea, which after modification will be able to send. So after send I need to back to show this new comment in div.

How I can achieve this?

Here is the      http://jsfiddle.net/4d56n5h4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

do you mean like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Amin52J/4d56n5h4/10/)**?

```
$('.commentEdit').click(function(){
    if($(this).text()=='Edit'){ $(this).parent().prev('.commentDescription').prop('contenteditable',true);
        $(this).parent().prev('.commentDescription').focus();
        $(this).text('Save');
    }
    else{
        $(this).text('Edit');
        //code to save the comment
    }
});
$('.commentDescription').blur(function(){
    $(this).prop('contenteditable',false);
});
```

you can save the comment on the blur event of `.commentDescription`

Comment: Ooo thanks! Nice, but also could you tell me how to activate this blur after click enter button? Or better solution would be changing Edit span to Save. I mean that firstly we click "Edit" and now "Edit" change property of ".commentDescription" to true and "Edit" become a "Save" option. Could you also help me with this?

Comment: check out the answer again

Comment: One more thing... How to set focus, until we click Save? I want to lose focus after saving changes...

Comment: Not this, this one I know. I mean this blue frame when ".commentDescription" become focus - it shows us that this field is active.

Comment: @Lui you can't force it to maintain focus, that would prevent interacting with other elements on the page. you could apply some styles like a background color and a border to make it look like a textfield, though. The blue frame you see is done by the browser.

Comment: the focus is not controllable, but here's a workaround http://jsfiddle.net/Amin52J/4d56n5h4/12/

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow ooo I didn't know it :) Thank you for explaining. I'm quite new in front-end :)

Comment: @AminJafari thank you very much for this solution! It's exactly what I want to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `contenteditable` property to `true`

```
<div id="comment" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

If you use jQuery, for editing:

```
$('#comment').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
```

for removing edition:

```
$('#comment').removeAttr('contenteditable');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a CSS-only solution, but it is not recommended. I am going to provide it simply for curiosity's sake, and to demonstrate the diversity of solutions available. It involves invoking a property which is supported by mozilla/chrome/safari, but for which official induction to the CSS3 standard never happened: the [`user-modify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-modify) property.

In my example, the content of a div becomes editable when clicking on a checkbox. This supports full rich-text paste.

I'm also using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to determine when the checkbox is checked, and an [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to then apply the property in question.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5gfamd7d/) is a jsFiddle example that includes some extra styling. Below is the bare-bones example.

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .content {
    user-modify: read-write;
    -moz-user-modify: read-write;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"> Edit

<div class="content">
    This is the content, only editable when the checkbox above is checked.
</div>
```